# Why does Pester say this function was called 0 times yet I can confirm it's being called when I run the script?

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, pester

In my powershell script I check a remote computer to see if is a virtual machine or physical. If it is a virtual machine I call a custom function to restore vm snapshot if not virtual I skip it. I've tested the script and it works but Pester says the restore vm function is never called. Looking for any help I can get.

Script:

```
foreach ($VMServer in $VMpool) {

        $serverType = (Invoke-RemoteServer -Server $VMServer -Username $VMPoolUsername -Password $VMPoolPassword -WithoutConfigurationName -ScriptBlock {Get-CimInstance win32_computersystem}).Model

        if ($serverType -eq "Virtual Machine") {

            Write-Output "    -Restore $BaseSnapShotForTesting snapshot on $VMServer"

            Restore-CineVMSnapshot -CheckpointName $BaseSnapShotForTesting -VMServer $VMServer -HostVMServer $HostVMServer `
                -Username $HostVMServerUsername -Password $HostVMServerPassword
        } else {
            Write-Output "    *$VMServer is NOT a Virtual Machine. Skipping Restore*"
        }
    }
```

Test:

```
            foreach ($testVM in $testVMPool) {
                Mock Invoke-RemoteServer {return $true}
                Assert-MockCalled Restore-CineVMSnapshot 1 -ParameterFilter {

                    $CheckpointName -and
                    $VMServer -eq $testVM -and
                    $HostVMServer -and
                    $Username -and
                    $Password
                } -Scope It
            }

        }
```

Comment: I think you need `Mock Invoke-RemoteServer {return @{Model='Virtual Machine'}}`. Where do you mock `Restore-CineVMSnapshot`?

Comment: Holy crap that worked!! Thank you Mathias

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `if` statement in your script, `Invoke-RemoteServer` must return *at least* one object with a `Model` property, the value of which is `"Virtual Machine"`, in order for the expected branch to execute.

Try changing the mocked definition:

```
Mock Invoke-RemoteServer {
    return @{Model = 'Virtual Machine'}
}
```